# Rselenium remove div element

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I want to remove a div element from a webpage using *RSelenium*.  Here is a MWE where I want to remove the `<div id="header">`.  I can find the element.  How can I make it disappear?

## MWE

```
library(RSelenium)

url <- 'https://ropensci.org'

## These two lines will pull the latest docker image of firefox and run it
system("docker pull selenium/standalone-firefox:latest")
system("docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox:latest")

drvr <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(port = 4445L)
drvr$open()
drvr$navigate(url)
drvr$screenshot(display = TRUE)

drvr$findElement("xpath", '//div[@id="header"]')
```

## More Context

I have a webpage where a div header floats around (rather than staying fixed at the top) as I'm expanding collapsed checkboxes and then clicking on the checkboxes.  That div header gets in the way of clicking other elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this to the active session you can remove (actually makes it hidden) the element but you have to use JavaScript. RSelenium has an `executeScript()` method as part of the driver class ([docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/RSelenium.pdf)).

Something like this should do it, you might have to tinker as I do not have access to your particular webpage/instance:

```
drvr$executeScript("return document.getElementById('header').remove();")
```

EDIT: You can also remove it with regex on the static page source HTML if you just want to remove it for parsing static content. But it seemed like that was not your use case. Let me know if an example there would be of interest to you as well.

Comment: That's terrific.  Works well.  Thank you.

Comment: For future searchers, I actually had a class tag so I had to adapt this terrific solution slightly. I used @GeoffreyGrimm's approach with a jQuery removal solution found here: stackoverflow.com/a/4777105/1000343